# How to calculate WinForms TrackBar each tick position?

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I use a TrackBar control to represent a time scale - every hour corresponds to a tick on the TrackBar. I also have a Panel just underneath the TrackBar which hosts icons representing events tied to hours. I have to place icon under corresponding tick of the TrackBar. The problem here is calculating pixel distance between ticks.

I went to check and found the following code in TrackBarRenderer.cs.

```
float inc = ((float)bounds.Width - lineWidth) / ((float)numTicks - 1);
...
float x = bounds.X + ((float)(numTicks - 1)) * inc;
```

"inc" variable is the distance between ticks, while "x" is each individual tick position. "numTicks" is pretty self explanatory, "lineWidth" is a hard-coded constant with value of "2".

I used "inc" formula and with some slight changes I was able to calculate position of each tick fairly accurate with little error on a machine running Windows 7. However, when I launched my program on Windows 10, position error was too noticeable even with 0 - 10 TrackBar.

Is there any solution which will work with every Windows version?

Comment: That this isn't possible has been a notorious problem for the past 25 years.  The native control has a [dedicated message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tbm-getptics) to return the tic marks but they screwed it up by not including the first and last one.  Win10 problems with eyeballing locations are usually dpiAware problems.

Comment: Could you please give an example how to retrieve positions using that message?

Comment: You're just missing the left/right margins of the TrackBack, which is 12 pixels (both left and right).